# the alert function in phonegap program does not work in the android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, cordova, alert, phonegap-plugins

```
now,the problem i am facing when i run the project in the LogCat
```

> 1 the TAG-Trace TEXT-error opening trace file:no such file or directory found (2)

when i click on the text for which onclick function is defined i don't get anything the error states

> 2 the TAG-web console TEXT-uncaught Typeerror:cannot call the method 'alert' of undefined at file:///android_assets/www.index.html:27
>
> navigator.notification.alert(

my coding is

```
    <html>
  <head>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alertDismissed
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>

in the case of the Accelerometer project nothing comes except whatever is given in the paragraph tag...where would i have committed mistake...i have no idea about it.

**i have tried with almost all the examples but the alert function does not function**


**i have tried both ways trying out with the example and then by copying all the files like the jar,cordova.js,xml and cordova folder**

now what should i do??? please help!!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (networkState == Connection.NONE)
{
  alert('No internet connection ');
 };
```

Comment: someone....please reply...and give me a solution for this problem........
now,i have realised tht there is somethung wrong in my procedure...

Comment: could someone help me out with this  ..i have tried the exact way as in phonegap.com but after i set the environment variable ...to test when i type ant in cmd i get it as a bad command....please help

Comment: I HAVE FOUND THE ANSWER FOR IT....

THE MISTAKE I COMMITTED WAS..........
   
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">'.......

WHEREAS, I HAD TO CHANGE THE VERSION OF CORDOVA IN THE JAVASCRIPT TAG..AS I WAS USING CORDOVA 2.3.0

I FOUND THE ANSWER ON MY OWN WITHOUT ANYONE'S HELP